# What is the smallest system to apply nonlocal quantum LDPC codes?

Tags: error-correction

I just learned that there are very promising nonlocal low-density parity check codes (LDPC) codes for quantum error correction. What is the smallest number of qubits necessary to carry out these algorithms?